# How do I fix over-exaggerated curves when using the SubSurf modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface, bevel

I've stumbled across this problem when using the *Subdivision Subsurface* modifier along with the *Bevel* modifier. I don't want the top open surface of my mesh to curve too much like in the picture below. How do I fix it?

[image: Weird curve-like shapes]

[image: 2]

Comment: Since you accepted the given answer: when using _Simple_ instead of _Catmull-Clark_, you get more geometry but the smoothing effect - which is often the desired effect of the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier - is gone. Do you need lots of geometry for e.g. displacement or do you want to smoothen the mesh? Smoothening doesn't work with _Simple_ so you can delete the modifier. And if you don't need it for displacement, it only makes the object unnecessarily complex and resource-heavy (especially on higher levels like 4) so you can delete it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the *Subdivision Subsurface* to *Simple*

Comment: As I wrote in the other comment, I still wonder how this solution worked for the OP. Either the _Sudivision Surface_ modifier wasn't really needed then the most simple solution would be: remove it. Or it's not needed for smoothing, but to get a (much) higher mesh resolution - but the object in the screenshot doesn't look like that. Actually there are ways to (really) fix this and keep the smoothening effect by loop cuts or other corrections to the original mesh, but this depends on the mesh itself and what it should look like in the end. But, it's an accepted answer... why do I care anyway.

Comment: Well, you are right. This wouldn't work in all use-cases. In this case, he/she just got lucky that it got fixed with this. Honestly, even i dont know any better way that to go into edit mode and start arranging the vertices to make it smoother

Comment: As I said - if you need the smoothening of the _Subdivision Surface_ (which it is the most common use) it's not just not working in all cases, but it's not working at all. I suspect that because of the _Bevel_ modifier before the _Subdivision Surface_, the smoothening effect was so minimal (as is visible in the screenshot) that the OP actually didn't realize that the modifier got absolutely useless for this case with the "Simple" option.